# Python refresh sqlite3 connection to retrieve latest values

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a Djanjo application which allows users to enter data which is submitted to a database.

This database is immediately accesed via python scripts running on the same machine.

### Scenario

1. User logs in Django website from Raspberry Pi (RPi)
2. User enters desired data.
3. Data submitted to database.
4. User pushes push button connected to RPi, which prompts database query.
5. Separate python scripts perform calculations based on user input.

My problem is that if step 4 is performed immediately after step 3, the query does not get the latest data entered by the user, but previous data already stored in the database.

If the user presses the push button, 30 seconds later, then, the query will be performed succesfully.

My code to get latest data from database:

```
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Line3_Data.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT tact FROM LineOEE03 ORDER BY tact desc limit 1")
        current_tact = c.fetchone()


       tact   
----------------- 
        45        <- old value retrieved     
        60        <- new value from step 3 not retrieved   
        60        <- new value from step 3 not retrieved
```

Is there any way to refresh the connection to make sure that only the very latest values are retrieved?

### EDIT

Write to database occurs very quickly. It is immediately visible when refreshing `sqlitebrowser`. After refreshing the `sqlitebrowser`, checking to see that the write has occured, the old value is still retrieved.

Around 30 seconds need to pass to read the new value.

Comment: I'd look at the `write` rather than the `read`. Did you commit the write?

Comment: Will edit the question to clarify. I can see the write immediately using `sqlitebrowser`. It is logged immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing a `conn.commit()` before the read should get your connection session up to date. Then you will see the last status of the data.

Comment: Thanks! Overlooked something so important!!

Comment: It's easy to forget for the read... You can also open the connection setting autocommit = True if that fits your needs. Good luck